# How to create multiple text area at the time of edit option using PHP and JavSscript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am creating multiple text area using `+` button and I need to do the same operation when edit option is also there using PHP and JavaScript. Here is my code:

```
 <div style="width:24%; float:left; padding:10px;">No of questions : 
     <input name="no_of_question" id="ques" class="form-control" placeholder="no of question" value="<?php if($_REQUEST['edit']) { echo $getcustomerobj->no_of_question; } else { echo $_REQUEST['no_of_question']; } ?>" type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">
                                                        
     <div id="err_msg_name" style="font-size:12px; color:#FF0000; text-align: center;"></div>
     </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
     <div style="padding-bottom:10px;">
    Questions : <input type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="plus" id="plus" value="+" onClick="addQuestionField();"><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" name="minus" id="minus" value="-" onClick="deleteQuestionField();">
    </div>
    <div id="container">
                                                  
     <div>
     <div style="width:24%; float:left; padding:10px;">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="questions0" id="questions" placeholder="Questions"  style="background:#FFFFFF;"  rows="2"><?php if($_REQUEST['edit']) { echo $getcustomerobj->questions; } else { echo $_REQUEST['questions']; } ?></textarea>
    </div>
                                                      
    <div style="float:left;margin-top:37px;">
    <?php
$status=array("status"=>'1');
     $feeddata=$db->kf_answertype->find($ustatus);
    ?>
    <div style="float:left; margin-right:10px;">
    <?php
    foreach($feeddata as $v){
    ?>
    <input type="radio" name="answer_type0" id="answer_type0" onClick="selectScale(this.value,'0');" value="<?php echo $v['_id']; ?>"> <?php echo $v['answertype'];  ?> 
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; margin-top:-10px;display:none;" id="scaleid0"><select class="form-control" id="nscale0" name="noofscale0">
    <option value="">Select Answer Type</option>
    <?php
$status=array("status"=>'1');
     $feeddata=$db->kf_scale->find($ustatus);
    foreach($feeddata as $v){
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $v['_id']; ?>" <?php if($getcustomerobj->no_of_scale == $v['_id'] or $_REQUEST['no_of_scale'] == $v['_id']){ print 'selected'; } ?>><?php echo $v['noofscale']; ?></option>                           
     <?php } ?>                 
    </select>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>                                                 
     </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
         </div>
                                                   
     </div>
    </div>
```

My JavaScript function is given below:

```
<script>
 function addQuestionField(){
    var get =$("#ques").val();
    if(get==null || get==''){
        alert('Please add no of questions');
    }else{
        var counter = 0;
        if (counter > 0){
            return;
        }else{
             counter++;
              <?php
                   $status=array("status"=>'1');
                   $feeddata=$db->kf_answertype->find($ustatus); 
            ?>
            <?php
                 $status=array("status"=>'1');
                $feeddatascale=$db->kf_scale->find($ustatus);
            ?>
             for(var i=1;i<get;i++){
                 
                  $('#container').append('<div><div style="width:24%; float:left; padding:10px;"> <textarea class="form-control" name="questions'+ i +'" id="questions" placeholder="Questions"  style="background:#FFFFFF;"  rows="2"><?php if($_REQUEST['edit']) { echo $getcustomerobj->questions; } else { echo $_REQUEST['questions']; } ?></textarea></div><div style="float:left;margin-top:37px;"><div style="float:left; margin-right:10px;"><?php foreach($feeddata as $v){?> <input type="radio" name="answer_type'+i+'" id="answer_type0" onClick="selectScale(this.value,'+i+');" value="<?php echo $v['_id']; ?>"> <?php echo $v['answertype']; ?> <?php }?></div><div style="float:left; margin-top:-10px;display:none;" id="scaleid'+i+'"><select class="form-control" id="nscale'+i+'" name="noofscale'+i+'"><option value="">Select Answer Type</option><?php foreach($feeddatascale as $v){ ?><option value="<?php echo $v['_id']; ?>" <?php if($getcustomerobj->no_of_scale == $v['_id'] or $_REQUEST['no_of_scale'] == $v['_id']){ print 'selected'; } ?>><?php echo $v['noofscale']; ?></option><?php } ?></select></div><div style="clear:both;"></div></div><div style="clear:both;"></div></div>');
                
             }
             
        }
    }
}
function deleteQuestionField(){
    var get =$("#ques").val();
    var textareas = $('#container textarea');

  if (textareas.length !== 0) {
    textareas.last().remove();

    $('#ques').val(textareas.length - 1);
  }
}
</script>
```

Here I can create the multiple text-area,radio button using `+` button which depends on `no of questions` field value. Here I need to do the same thing when the following condition is true.

```
if($id!='' && $_REQUEST['edit']==1){
}
```

at the time of page reload if the above condition is true then no need to click on `+` button, the multiple field should also created.

Comment: If you want to add another field, use this one: `$("element").clone().insertAfter("element:last");`

Comment: no,you are getting wrong.Please read my post again.Whatever the operation are happening using `+` button exact same process should happen using the givem condition.